# OS X Apache giving 503 error for anything in /api directory

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, osx-lion, 503-error

I have a locally hosted website that uses Smarty templates, I'm trying to get started on building an API for the site.

I've used [virtualhost.sh](http://code.google.com/p/virtualhost-sh/) to create a local virtual host for this and other sites.

I've discovered that if I put a directory called api at the root of any of these virtual hosts  I will get a 503 error when I try to access anything inside.

I am using mod-rewrite but so far only to append a .php extension when needed.

Here are the error logs for a request:

```
[Thu Feb 09 13:42:37 2012] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Thu Feb 09 13:49:06 2012] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:8080 (localhost) failed
[Thu Feb 09 13:49:06 2012] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
```

The middle line gave me a clue to look in my hosts file because why would a request go to `[fe80::1]:8080`? I commented out that line and tried again, this time the error was in connecting to the standard `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

I have concluded that perhaps there is some config file somewhere picking up the underlying request of `localhost/api` and pointing it somewhere other than my virtual host. At this point my ability to fix the problem fails me. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The proxy configuration is trying to pass the request to localhost:8080.
Whatever destination server is not accepting requests on port 8080